# how to add ipa files into itunes in windows machine?

Tags: iphone, windows, ipa, provisioning-profile

I have created a **Provisioning Profile** and an .ipa for my application. I had to send this to my client who uses Windows machines. I am aware of how to add the .ipa files in MAC machines but when it comes to **Windows machine**, I am not able to find the App section in the left side bar of iTunes Window. SO i am not able to drag and drop the **provisioning profile and the .ipa file into itunes from windows machine**. Can someone please help me on how to get out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your client download a free app off of the App Store, maybe not having any applications in the target library makes iTunes think it shouldn't show that item in the menu.

I'm also thinking that you can turn on/off individual menu items inside the iTunes preferences, so maybe check there?

[image]

Comment: I still havent submitted the App to AppStore...I wanted the client to test forst before submitting to AppStore....

Comment: Have your client download a free app. Any app.

Comment: In the iTunes preferences under the General tab, check the Apps box. If this helps you, please vote and mark the answer as accepted!